# How to load .mrc file in python?

Tags: python-2.7, file, ioerror

I am trying to load a .mrc file in python. But, I am getting error.

Code(ReadMrcTest.py)::

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

imgPath = 'usr/Task1/emd-62.mrc' #Even for 'usr/task1/emd-62.mrc', same error
image = h5py.File(imgPath)
print image
```

*Error:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ReadMrcTest.py", line 8, in <module> 
    image = h5py.File(imgPath) 
  File "/usr/s029/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 271, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
  File "/usr/s029/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 126, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-nCYoKW-build/h5py/_objects.c:2840)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-nCYoKW-build/h5py/_objects.c:2798)
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 98, in h5py.h5f.create (/tmp/pip-nCYoKW-build/h5py/h5f.c:2284)
**IOError: Unable to create file (Unable to open file: name = '/usr/task1/emd-62.mrc', errno = 17, error message = 'file exists', flags = 15, o_flags = c2)**
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message references `/usr/task1/emd-62.mrc`, while your code sample reads `'usr/Task1/EMD-2.mrc'` - as far as I know, paths are case-sensitive on unix-like systems - did you simple get the path wrong?

Comment: @ventiseis : Thanks for your response. I have corrected the paths now. Even then I am getting the same error.

Comment: You write `usr/Task1/emd-62.mrc` in your `python` file, the error message says `/usr/task1/emd-62.mrc` -- two different paths.

Comment: Even if I write `usr/task1/emd-62.mrc` in python file, then also I am getting the same error.

Comment: I don't want to be a nitpicker, _but_ `/usr/task1/emd-62.mrc` is a completly different path as `usr/Task1/emd-62.mrc`. If you omit the leading `/`, the python will search relatively to the current directory. Something _is_ wrong here, because the `/` is included in the error message. And additionaly, `/usr/task1` looks like a strange directory to me, unless you created it yourself,

Comment: Er, did you try `h5py.File('myfile.hdf5','r')` to open it readonly? Its documented [here](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html).

Comment: Formatted the code and the error trace